# StackOverflowError in SemanticGraph object

Tags: java, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I am running the neural dependency parser from CoreNLP 3.8.0 large-scale by using Apache Spark. The CoreNLP pipeline I am using for parsing is this:

```
public static StanfordCoreNLP StanfordDepNNParser(){
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("language", "english");
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, depparse");
    props.put("depparse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz");
    props.put("parse.originalDependencies", true);

    return new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
}
```

However, after a while, I get the following error:

```
18/06/08 08:16:40 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 136.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 140, server.com): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:630)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1526)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph.toCompactStringHelper(SemanticGraph.java:1541)
    . . . .
```

Unfortunately, I cannot locate the exact sentence (or document) that triggers this exception. Is it possible to make some sort of check upfront that would just skip this sentence?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking to solve the halting problem. I would rather suggest to turn in a bug report to prevent the tool from crashing.

Comment: Without the sentence it's hard to debug this. It may actually just an unusually long sentence exhausting the Java stack. The code itself, from looking at it, appears correct.

Comment: It's not an unusually long sentence, because I am eliminating the sentences longer than 100 words before doing the parsing. Any other idea what might be causing this?